# Graphic glitch problem

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS (  GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile  )

I have all my Nvidia driver installed.

Can someone help me fix this ?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome fixed it , now i'm using Firefox ! much better for Privacy.